# How to change div height with screen size in html?

Tags: html, css, screen

I am creating a parallax scrolling website. You can see it on https://titanoboa.info. However, my div is not in accordance with the text and the screen size. Could some one give me the code so that if it is viewed on a mobile device or a large screen, it changes with the text? Thank you so much, I am a beginner and this is very new to me.

If you need my code, it is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide">
<style>
.parallax1 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Titanoboa_2_%287684792104%29.jpg);

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  
  
  
  
}

.parallax2 {
   /* The image used */
  background-image: url(https://cdn.britannica.com/13/132613-050-0093E19F/Titanoboa-cerrejonensis-image-anaconda-comparison-vertebrae-world.jpg);

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

p {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  
}

h2 {
 font-family: "Audiowide", sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="parallax1"></div>

<div style="color:white;height:175px;background-color:rgb(46, 44, 46);font-size:15px;">

<h2>What was Titanoboa?</h2>
<p style=" padding-left: 10px;"> Titanoboa lived over 60 million years ago in an era called the Paleocene Epoch. Its fossils were found in a coal mine in Colombia, where it gets its name, titanoboa cerrejonensis. Sounds scary, right? Don't worry it gets much worse than that. You have probably have heard of huge snakes that "swallow" up humans, like the anaconda, and pythons. But titanoboa makes those seem laughable. Introducing the 40 foot snake, titanoboa. Imagine two adult giraffes laid on their sides, one after the other, and titanoboa would still be longer! In addition, this creature was 3 feet in thickness, so up to an adult's waist, and weighed 1.4 tons, the same as a sudan!   </p>
</div>
<div class="parallax1"></div>

<div style="color:white;height:220px;background-color:rgb(46, 44, 46);font-size:15px;">

<h2>What did it eat and where did it live?</h2>
<p style=" padding-left: 10px;"> Did you know that the largest snake living today was only half the size of titanoboa? It was so big it could swallow a hippopotamus whole, but unfourtunately for it, they didn't exist at the time. They lived in swamps and rivers, where they could easily find their favourite food, large fish. It liked a warm climate, which made the animal so huge. It could be found in Colombia, Venezuela, Brazil, and neighbouring countries. The amazon rainforest was a perfect place for it to rule. Although scientists have only found about 30 individuals, titanoboa was most likely a huge presence for the animals of the time. When titanoboa killed, it did so in an extremely sophisticated manner. In a sharp attack, it quickly wrapped its large body around its victim and strangled it. When it died, it was swallowed whole. And on the inside, it was even more of a nightmare. It faced compression of weight more than the Brooklyn bridge, which helped it digest, and it stayed there for a very long time. Titanoboa's massive size helped it find food very easily. You can see the difference in size just from the vertebrae. In the picture below, the left vertebrae is the anaconda, and on the right, titanoboa.</p>
</div>

<div class="parallax2"></div>

<div style="color:white;height:150px;background-color:rgb(46, 44, 46);font-size:15px;">

<h2>How did it get so big? </h2>
<p style=" padding-left: 10px; font-size:15px;">Titanoboa loved the hot climate, and that had a lot of effect on its size. When climate gets hotter, animals get much bigger. Back then, temperatures were at least 15 degrees hotter than today. And with climate change on the rise, titanoboa might just come back. Luckily for us, that would take millions of years. The only reason titanoboa died out, was because the climate plummeted and suited smaller snakes, like the ones we see today. It is very interesting for scientists to find large creatures like titanoboa in million years after dinosaurs died out. </p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks again, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css media queries to detect if a user is on a device with a smaller width (mobile device) and if they are, you can style your text a certain way.

### Code:

```
<!--Now if the user is on a mobile device screen width, the background will become lightblue-->
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      body {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
    }
```

Or in your case for an example.:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .myDiv {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

Link to a nice tutorial on media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp